# Expand range of numbers in file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with delimited integers which I've extracted from elsewhere and dumped into a file. Some lines contain a range, as per the below:

```
Files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are OK
Users 1,2,3-9,10 have problems
Cars 1-5,5-10 are in the depot
Trains 1-10 are on time
```

Any way to expand the ranges on the text file so that it returns each individual number, with the , delimiter preserved? The text either side of the integers could be anything, and I need it preserved.

```
Files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are OK
Uses 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 have problems
Cars 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are in the depot
Trains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are on time
```

I guess this can be done relatively easily with awk, let alone any other scripting language. Any help very much appreciated

Comment: This question has been asked before but I fail to find the link, meanwhile, see this http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1207056.html

Comment: you are right, it can be done by awk, how far have you been?  And I don't see a question here...  regarding the requirements, Can the overlap happen on two ranges? are the ranges always sorted? You need a generic solution or just for some specific input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't tagged with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) but I'd recommend it in this case:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",", $1..$2)/ge' file
```

This substitutes all occurrences of one or more digits, followed by a hyphen, followed by one or more digits. It uses the numbers it has captured to create a list from the first number to the second and joins the list on a comma.

The `e` modifier is needed here so that an expression can be evaluated in the replacement part of the substitution.

To avoid repeated values and to sort the list, things get a little more complicated. At this point, I'd recommend using a script, rather than a one-liner:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

while (<>) {
    s/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",", $1..$2)/ge;
    if (/(.*\s)((\d+,)+\d+)(.*)/) {
        my @list = sort { $a <=> $b } uniq split(",", $2);
        $_ = $1 . join(",", @list) . $4 . "\n";
    }
} continue {
    print;
}
```

After expanding the ranges (like in the one-liner), I've re-parsed the line to extract the list of values. I've used `uniq` from `List::MoreUtils` (a core module) to remove any duplicates and sorted the values.

Call the script like `perl script.pl file`.

Comment: I came to the same answer. I found something wierd when trying stuff out though. If i did `perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/print $1..$2/ge'`, it prints the numbers before the start of the line. Any idea why?

Comment: @123 yeah, because you're evaluating a `print` command (which goes straight to stdout).

Comment: But this produces repeated indices.

Comment: Thanks very much. This works nicely. No perl skills at all - I've amended it so that it only picks up lines with a specific string. Seems like a similar syntax to sed, maybe i should delve in a bit with perl.

Comment: @captainyossarian yeah, the syntax of a regex match or substitution is similar to sed but much more powerful. And you get to assign things to variables, which can come in handy ;)

Comment: @tom I've amended this back and forth but can't quite pick up the syntax. Could you help me applying it to lines in a file that contain a specific string? can only seem to get it working with lines beginning with (^) or ending with ($). apologies in advance for my amateurishness.

Comment: @captainyossarian you'd have to show an example of what you mean. I'd suggest doing so in a new question, showing a sample of your input/output and the code you're trying to use. Feel free to use this code as a starting point.

Comment: In the one liner, i've had it matching lines that start with the string 'when'. i'd like it to match with lines _containing_ the string 'when', rather than beginning with. example, lines beginning with 'when': `perl -pe 's/^when(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",", $1..$2)/ge' file`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `awk`:

```
{
    result = "";
    count = split($0, fields, /[ ,-]+/, seps);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        if (fields[i] ~ /[0-9]+/) {
            if (seps[i] == ",") {
                numbers[fields[i]] = fields[i];
            } else if (seps[i] == "-") {
                for (j = fields[i] + 1; j <= fields[i+1]; j++) {
                    numbers[j] = j;
                }
            } else if (seps[i] == " ") {
                numbers[fields[i]] = fields[i];
                c = asort(numbers);
                for (r = 1; r < c; r++) {
                    result = result numbers[r] ",";
                }
                result = result numbers[c] " ";
            }
        } else {
            result = result fields[i] seps[i];
        }
    }
    print result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/[0-9,-]+/) {
    split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),numsIn,/,/)
    numsOut = ""
    delete seen
    for (i=1;i in numsIn;i++) {
        n = split(numsIn[i],range,/-/)
        for (j=range[1]; j<=range[n]; j++) {
            if ( !seen[j]++ ) {
                numsOut = (numsOut=="" ? "" : numsOut ",") j
            }
        }
    }
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) numsOut substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are OK
Users 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 have problems
Cars 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are in the depot
Trains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are on time
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{while(match($0, /[0-9]+-[0-9]+/))
          {k=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); 
           split(k,a,"-"); 
           f=a[1]; 
           for(j=a[1]+1; j<=a[2]; j++) f=f","j; 
           sub(k,f)}}1' file

Files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are OK
Users 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 have problems
Cars 1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10 are in the depot
Trains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are on time
```

note that the `Cars 1-5,5-10` will end up two `5` values when expanded due to overlapping ranges.